# Backbone.js calling render after collection is populated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to call render after fetch of a collection.

In my initialize method I have:

```
this.collection.bind('all', this.render, this);
this.collection.fetch();
```

In IE it seems that sometimes it tries to render, before the collection has data.  Collections don't seem to have a 'change' event that can be bound to, is there a better way to ensure that the collection has been fetched before rendering?

Thanks!

EDIT:

If I refresh the page, it seems to always work, however if I click in the address bar again and the page loads, it doesn't ever work.

Comment: Is the reset event what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like it, so I'm starting with an empty collection, then using fetch() to populate it.  After that, I want to call the render

Comment: Added an additional comment above, it's isolated only when you go direct from the address bar, if I refresh the page - it works.

Comment: You could try 'view.listenTo(collection, 'sync', view.render);' from within the view instead of the bind method above. You might want to replace view with 'this'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that data has been fetched before rendering it, then I'd suggest using jQuery's `deferred` object:

```
this.collection.deferred = this.collection.fetch();
self = this;
this.collection.deferred.done(function() {
    self.collection.render();
  }
);
```

Basically anything you put into the function you send to `done` will only be called *after* fetch is, well, done.

More on deferreds:

- http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/07/rewriting-my-guaranteed-callbacks-code-with-jquery-deferred/
- http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Backbone's [Catalog of Events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events) sounds like you want to listen to the [reset](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset) event

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
this.collection.fetch();
```

Normally in Backbone.js one would use on() to bind a callback to an object.

Answer (score 0):

The following should definitely work, it worked for me...

instead of the below

```
this.collection.fetch();
```

use this

```
this.collection.fetch(async: false);
```