# BackboneJS - listening to nested model changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**The short version** : I have a Backbone model which has as one of its attributes, a second Backbone model.  A function in the first model changes the state of the second model, but my view, which is listening for changes to the first model, does not seem to be picking up the state of the second model, despite any amount of logging that suggests otherwise (I've been logging  `this` at various points to confirm scope, etc.). How can I fix this?

**The long version** : I have a Backbone model `Course`, which represents an academic course, and a model `NameList`, which represents the list of students enrolled in a `Course`.  A `Course` "has-a" `NameList`. A `NameList` is backed by a single text file on the server.

I want to have a function in the `Course` model called `importNameList` which creates a new `NameList` model and causes that `NameList` model to go and `fetch` its data from the backend. Since my view, `CourseView` is listening for changes to the `Course` model, and a `Course` model has-a `NameList`, it seems like this should update the view accordingly.  My problem is that it doesn't.

**What I want to do**

```
var course = new Course();
var courseView = new CourseView({model : course});
courseView.model.importNameList('students.txt'); // Will cause view to re-render
```

**What I have to do**

```
var course = new Course(); // same 
var courseView = new CourseView({model : course}); // same
courseView.model.importNameList('students.txt'); // same
courseView.render(); // Argh, manually calling this is ugly.
```

Here is my code with logging statements. The models extend `Backbone.DeepModel` only because I thought it might solve my problem, but it didn't.

**Console output**

```
[console] var course = new Course();
[console] var courseView = new CourseView({model : course});
[console] course.importNameList('students.txt');

          Course >>> importNameList
          NameList >>> initialize()
          NameList >>> fetch()
          GET http://localhost/files/students.txt 200 OK 16ms    
          CourseView >>> render() // Render starts before fetch completes
          CourseView <<< render() // Render finishes before fetch completes
          Course <<< importNameList
          NameList <<< fetch()

[console] courseView.render();

          CourseView >>> render()
          alice
          bob
          charlie
          dan
          erica
          fred
          george
          CourseView <<< render()
```

**Course.js**

```
var Course = Backbone.DeepModel.extend({

    defaults : {
        nameList : new NameList()
    },

    initialize: function(options) {

        if (options && options.nameList) {
            this.set({nameList : options.nameList});
        }

    },

    importNameList : function(fileName) {

        console.log("Course >>> importNameList");
        var nameList = new NameList({fileName : fileName});
        this.set({nameList : nameList});
        console.log("Course <<< importNameList");
    }
});
```

**NameList.js**

```
var NameList = Backbone.DeepModel.extend({

    defaults : {
        fileName : 'new.txt',
        names : []
    },

    initialize: function(options) {

        console.log("NameList >>> initialize()");
        var model = this;

        if (options && options.fileName) {
            model.set({fileName : options.fileName});
        }
        model.fetch();
    },

    fetch : function() {
        console.log("NameList >>> fetch()");
        var model = this;
        $.ajax({
            url : '/files/' + model.get('fileName'),
            success : function(response) {
                model.set({names : response.split('\n')});
                console.log("NameList <<< fetch()");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**CourseView.js**

```
var CourseView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function(options) {

        var view = this;
        if (options && options.model) {
            view.model = options.model;
        } else {
            view.model = new Course();
        }

        view.model.on('change', function() {
            view.render();
        });

    },

    render : function() {

        console.log("CourseView >>> render()");
        var names = this.model.get('nameList').get('names');
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            console.log(names[i]);
        }
        console.log("CourseView <<< render()");
        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: Why are you overriding `fetch` in NameList.js? This seems totally contrary to what backbone.js was made for. You shouldn't be calling ajax functions directly to update models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following.

**CourseView.js:**

```
// No changes.
```

**Within Course.js:**

```
importNameList : function(name) {

    var model = this;
    var nameList = new NameList({fileName : fileName});
    // Set the attribute silently (without triggering a change event)
    model.set({nameList : nameList}, {silent: true});
    nameList.fetch({
        success : function() {
            model.change(); // Manually fire a change event when fetch completes.
        }
    });
}
```

**Within NameList.js:**

```
fetch : function(options) {
    var model = this;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/files/' + model.get('fileName'),
        success : function(response) {
            model.set({lines : response.split('\n')});
            // Make the "success" callback.
            options.success();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to use jQuery a [`deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object. You can find more on using deferreds with backbone.js in [this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/07/rewriting-my-guaranteed-callbacks-code-with-jquery-deferred/).

I would add more specific info but I'm not really clear why you're overriding fetch, which seems like a recipe for disaster. I would stick to backbone's original fetch method and leave it out of NameList's initializer, call it instead from Course.js and use the deferred returned from it to guarantee that the steps after are run once the fetch is completed.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a sketch of one way you could do this. First take the `model.fetch();` line out of the `initialize` method of `NameList`, and call it instead in `importNameList`, using its return value (a deferred object) as the return value of `importNameList`:

```
var nameList = new NameList({fileName : fileName});
this.set({nameList : nameList});
return nameList.fetch()
```

Now that we are returning a deferred from `importNameList`, we can use it to guarantee that the fetch is complete before rendering:

```
this.deferred = courseView.model.importNameList('students.txt');
this.deferred.done(function() { courseView.render() });
```

I think that should do what you want, although I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: Your point about leaving it out of `initialize` is worth considering, but my backend doesn't exactly follow the plain vanilla RESTful interface assumptions of Backbone which is why I'm overriding `fetch`.

Comment: I see. Well basically the approach I use is to take the deferred returned from `fetch` and then call `done` on that, and pass a function with whatever I want to be run when the fetch is complete. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585137/backbone-js-calling-render-after-collection-is-populated/11590613#11590613